# getAudioSessionId from RemoteController in android

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I use RemoteController for manage music player and show current music ,and play ,pause and etc.

I want to add visualizer for layout showing current music playing,for that I need 
AudioSessionId ,how can I get this from another music player with RemoteController?

```
class RemoteControlService extends NotificationListenerService implements RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener
```

---

```
mVisualizer = new Visualizer(player.getAudioSessionId());//I haven't player in this mode(RemoteController)
```